# Domain Name pointed to name servers in US and then forwarded to a public IP in Asia

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, domain, hosting, nameserver

We are trying to host our website in our office. We have a very fast server with a public IP and an opensource cPanel installed. Our domain name is registered with a different provider and I couldn't redirect it to our public IP so I basically did create an account with inmotionhosting.com. I used their nameservers, the domain goes there and then added an A record for the public IP in inmotionhosting to redirect the domain name to the public IP assigned to the server we have.

It works fine, but I am sure it's not a good practice since there are too many redirections involved. Can anyone please suggest a better way to do achieve this?

By end of the day, we want our domain name to redirect to the public IP which is assigned to the server.

Looking forward to answers.

Comment: Transfer your domain to a registrar that allows to point host names wherever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using inmotion as a DNS hosting service. If you have the domain pointing to inmotion's nameservers and inmotion has an A record pointing to the correct server, that seems fine. There is a difference between "redirecting" and changing DNS records. Redirect implies you're visiting another server via HTTP/S and it's doing a 301/302 redirect to another server. If it's all being done using the correct DNS records, I see no problem.

Depending on who you buy the domain from, you may be able to just setup your A record there pointing to your server. I find it easier to use a 3rd party to host DNS since it makes it easier if you want to change registrars.

Comment: Thanks Nijave, I have changed DNS records in the domain setting to point it to inmotionhosting but then an A record in inmotionhositng to point to my server.